# How to enable more than one condition in dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, php, drop-down-menu

I have one dropdown list. When I select *"Others"*, *"Other Action textbox"* will enable.
When I select *"Classroom Training"* or *"On Job Training(OJT)"*, dropdown *"Proposed Training in Ilsas"* and textbox *"Proposed Training in Public"* will enable.
For the *"Others"* condition I have made it right.

Then, how can I add another conditions into JavaScript? This is because I have tried to combine the conditions into JavaScript but it's not successful.

```js
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
    function otherAction(val) {
        var otherAct = document.getElementById('otherAct');
        if(val=='Others') {
            otherAct.style.display = "block";
        } else {    
            otherAct.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Action: </td>
        <td>
            <select name="perAction" onchange="otherAction(this.value)"> 
                <option value="0"></option>                    
                <option value="Classroom Training">Classroom Training</option>
                <option value="Coaches and Mentoring by IM">Coaches and Mentoring by IM</option>
                <option value="On Job Training (OJT)">On Job Training (OJT)</option>
                <option value="Others">Others</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>Other Action: </td>
        <td><input name="otherAct" type="text" id="otherAct" /></td>
        <td>Proposed Training in Ilsas: </td>
        <td>
            <select name = "perIlsas">
                <option value="0"></option>                    
                <option value="Project Management">Project Management</option>
                <option value="Contract Management">Contract Management</option>
                <option value="Analytical Skill">Analytical Skill</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>Proposed Training in Public: </td>
        <td><input name="pubTraining" type="text" id="pubTraining" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use multiple `if-else` conditions

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
    function otherAction(val) {
        var otherAct = document.getElementById('otherAct');
        if(val=='Others') {
            otherAct.style.display = "block";
        } else if(val == 'On Job Training (OJT)'){    
             otherAct.style.display = "none";
             pubTraining.style.display = "block";
            // set display here either `block` or `none` according to your need
        }
        else{
             // set display here either block or none according to your need
        }
    }
</script>
```

**EDIT:**
First of all give some `id` attribute to that select box. and then,You can write another `else-if` condition checking like this

```
<select id="perIlsas" name = "perIlsas"> //assigning id attribute

else if(val == 'Coaches and Mentoring by IM'){ //another else-if condition    
       $('#perIlsas').prop('disabled', 'disabled'); //this will disable entire selectbox
        }
```

You can get to know more about `prop` in the [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: TQ. This is what I really want. But, why dropdownlist perIlsas cannot disable when I  choose Coaches and Mentoring by IM? Only textbox for pubTraining works.